# Checkbox 'off' value without JavaScript

Tags: html, checkbox

Does anyone have a *no JavaScript* way to make HTML checkbox still submit a value? As in if you check it the form submission will include a value A but if it is uncheck it still contains a value B?

While I figure there isn't any way, I'm working on a site which needs to still be function when JS is off, and this would be ideal.

Comment: We are in the era of HTML5, IPad, Android, and you still trying to support browser without JavaScript? That is blasphemy.

Comment: I try not to filter potential customers based on browser settings :P (try)

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this exact question, but I'm afraid it's NO - as pointed out in the answers. Although you can do it with javascript that feels a bit 'hacky'. So my interest in not using javascript would be because it isn't pretty, not to support browsers without javascript. Therefore this question seems to me very much valid in the current 'era'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML checkboxes aren't supposed to work that way. If you check the checkbox, the definied parameter name=value pair will be sent. If you uncheck it, it will not be sent. In the server side you just have to check the presence of the parameter name (or value in case of multiple checkboxes in a named group) in the parameter map and handle accordingly. If present, then it's checked. If absent, then it's not checked. Simple as that. You already know the "unchecked value" in the server side.

Answer (score 4):

You *might* be able to do it by having a hidden form element with the same `name`. However, different browsers may treat the priority of which one gets submitted (if the checkbox is checked) differently, so at best, it's a hacky solution.

Comment: this is a very good turnaround, but the priority may be an important issue.

Answer (score 0):

The way I worked one of these problems was to set a hidden form element that included all of the checkbox `names` delimited with a comma. Then, on the server side, I simply exploded this string and checked to see which checkboxes were on and off. It still felt like a hack, however, but I wasn't familiar with JavaScripts at the time, so that's what I ended up doing. Considering revising this at this time.

I hope this will help someone.